Generating B-frames before I-frame with ffmpeg (like XAVC)
Several files generated in XAVC have 2 B-frames before the I-frame and I've been trying to transcode those files using ffmpeg to match the structure at a lower resolution/bitrate, but I've been unable to do so. I was hoping that -force_key_frames source would do that, but it always makes the first frame a key frame, so is there a way to match the pict_type and have 2 B-frames before the I-frame while transcoding with ffmpeg?

How are you determining the order of the frames in the source?

This command outputs the frames and then also stepping through the ffmpeg code with a debugger:
ffprobe -show_entries frame=pts,pkt_pos,pict_type -of csv=p=0 -I test.mp4
